# Static Image not showing in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I am attempting to run a react-native application off of a pre-bundled file on disk.

When I build and run on my phone, it works fine, but when I do so in the Simulator, the static images do not show up. I am referencing them via the require('../assets/image_name.png') that has been the standard since 0.14.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would occur?

The bundle command that is running looks like 
`react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios --dev false --assets-dest ./ios`

Answer (score 0):

If using the Asset Catalog, it might be worth also checking whether Images.xcassets holds all your targets as shown in the below image.

[image]